# OleDBCommand, multiple commands

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

I have an access table that I am using to keep track of a number that increments whenever an export of other data occurs. In the

```
using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(DatabaseProvider + DatabaseFilePath))
{
      con.Open();
      using (OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
      {
           cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM IncrementingNumberTable WHERE [Num]=" + curr + ";";
           cmd.Connection = con;
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
      curr++;
      using (OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
      {
           cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO IncrementingNumberTable ([Num])VALUES(" + curr + ");";
           cmd.Connection = con;
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
}
```

The code works as intended but it is possible, though unlikely, that a connection error occurs in the second command, meaning that my incremented number is lost. This occurred while debugging and wouldn't be good while if it happened in a live system.

Comment: Wouldn't an UPDATE query be better suited once the record exists?  Use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.  Search "Database Transactions" for information on updating multiple records, etc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The way this would normally be handled in a database environment is with a transaction. This would cause a series of commands to succeed or fail as a block, and if an error occurs in the middle it rolls back everything to the initial state.

I've never done this personally with Access (done it many times with SQL Server, MySql, Postgres, etc), but there is an [OleDbConnection.BeginTransaction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.begintransaction?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0). There is a very nice example on this page showing how to use it.

Based on a [comment in the MSDN forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d056cd00-dfdb-4046-bb7c-5685bbdbe43e/oledb-transaction), it appears this works with Access' Jet database engine:

> Hi,
>
> Indeed Microsoft Jet doesn't support System.Transactions and TransactionScope.
>
> If you still want to use transactions, you can use native OleDB transactions: http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93ehy0z8.aspx
>
> Cheers,
>
> Florin

(credit [Florin Lazar - MSFT](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/florin%20lazar%20-%20msft/?ws=usercard-mini))

#### An alternative solution...

would be to do this operation in a single `update` command, instead of a `delete` followed by an `insert`. Something like this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE IncrementingNumberTable set [Num] = [Num] + 1 WHERE [Num]=" + curr + ";";
```